# Import71 and file permission in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, import, windows, e00

I am making a map for my thesis. While using ArcGIS, I must use Import71 to convert some .e00 files (in this particular case, political boundaries and Hydrography networks). When I select my output folder, I receive the message:

> E:\ File Path This file cannot be accessed. Make sure you have security privileges on the drive.

I use Windows 7.

Is this simply a Windows/administrator problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: most likely it is a permissions problem.  I'd create a subdir on the e: drive and assign permissions to that.

Answer (score 5):

I think import71.exe is flat out incompatible with Windows7. You could try finding the *import71.exe > r-click > Troubleshoot compatibilty*, which I did but without success. I didn't try every available option.

The command line [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) from the gdal utilities suite can translate the files just fine on windows 7 though:

```
ogr2ogr out_dir test.e00
```

Install from http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki

Answer (score 3):

In the Output Data Source you need to add the name of the folder you want to create, you don't just enter an existing folder. Also, you want to make sure to use short name folder like c:\coverage\ you can move it after creation to a long folder name with spaces.

Create C:\coverage\ folder, no spaces, 8 or less characters
In Import71 Output Data Source key in c:\coverage\newcover

Comment: Spaces in folder names is often a likely culprit for this type of error, especially using such an old application as Import71.